# Euler's method, no interval

Tags: numerical-methods

I have a problem on which I need to apply Euler's method - EXCEPT that I don't have one of the crucial components. Question and my thoughts below:

**Question:** Consider the initial value problem $\frac{dy}{dt}=\alpha t^{\alpha - 1}, y(0)=0$, where $\alpha > 0$. The true solution is $y(t)=t^{\alpha}$. Use the Euler method to solve the initial value problem for $\alpha = 2.5,1,5,1.1$ with stepsize $h=0.2,0.1,0.05$. Compute the solution errors at the nodes, and determine numerically the convergence orders of the Euler method for these problems.

**My thoughts:** I don't have the "interval" for t! I tried setting the problem up as follows:

$0 \leq t \leq b$, with $N = (b-0)/0.2 = 5b$ for $h=0.2$, but wasn't able to get anything conclusive.

Should I try $b = 1$, so that t is restricted to a range in which it shrinks?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Repeat what process? Also, I don't know what error tolerance to seek.

Comment: Yeah it did. thanks!

Comment: @Amzoti I picked say $\alpha = 2.5$ and $h = 0.2$. Then I obtained $|t^{2.5}-0.5t^{1.5}| \leq 10^{-2}$. Should I use W|A to solve for $t$, and then use that tolerance for my other values of $\alpha$ and $h$?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11543/discussion-between-anonymous-and-amzoti)